# I am trying to create a simple chat program by writing to a shared file on my network

Tags: delphi, timer

I am trying to use a timer to check the the timestamp of the file to check if it has been modified, if this is true it must add the line from the text file to a richedit. The problem is that it continually adds the line to the richedit every 1/4 second (timer interval). I have tried different methods but can't get it right.

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
Var
Filet : textfile;
filename, readtxt : string;
filedate1, filedate2 : integer;
begin

assignfile(filet, 'S:\share.talk');
filename := 'S:\share.talk';
filedate1 := FileAge(filename);

if filedate1 <> filedate2 then begin
reset(filet);
readln(filet, readtxt);
richedit1.lines.add(readtxt);
closefile(filet);
filedate2 := filedate1;
end;//if
end;
```

thanks for all help.

Comment: You've chosen the worst possible method to approach this. I seriously advise reconsidering your design, and consider using a proper database.

Comment: `P(this_design_proves_useful) = 0`

Comment: @JerryDodge:  Actually, I wouldn't be surprised if this is a self-instructional exercise - I've seen a number of students doing similar (as such, it's not a wholly bad idea because it leads into things like file-locking and concurrent access). One of them was amazed when I showed him how simple it is to implement this with a Delphi COM server and clients.

Comment: use Firebird SQL server - it I free and it has pushing of updates! :-D

Comment: I wouldn't even bother with a database. A simple client/server model with sockets would probably be better.

Comment: @Remy that all depends on whether OP wishes to keep track of historical messages... such as sending to an offline user.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: "A simple client/server model" Yes, that's what I was meaning ...

Comment: @MartynA: yes, but you mentioned using COM for that. I wouldn't use COM for communicating between different machines (DCOM maybe, but I have no experience with DCOM). I would use sockets or named pipes instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  I've never been a fan of DCom, nor used it for anything serious, but for the purpose of demoing a home-rolled chat app on a LAN it worked a treat.

Comment: Few opensource chats in Delphi - read the sources and do like they do.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/dreamchat/  // https://sourceforge.net/projects/visualirc/ // https://sourceforge.net/directory/language:delphi/os:windows/?q=chat

Comment: @RemyLebeau I would not suggest SQL for public networks, however for closed small networks or using Zebedee it would actually be easier:  your server should already make some moderators functions like keeping logins/passwords, allowing banning users, etc. It also has to deal with random disconnections, so clients should re-connect and catch-up. With SQL it is mostly for granted, with custom coding you would have to implement it from scratch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code

```
if filedate1 <> filedate2 then begin
reset(filet);
readln(filet, readtxt);
richedit1.lines.add(readtxt);
closefile(filet);
filedate2 := filedate1;
end;
```

the comparison between  `filedate` and `filedate2` assumes that these retain their values between calls to `Timer1Timer`.  They do **not**, because they are declared local to `Timer1Timer` and are therefore 'forgotten' between calls because they are stored on the stack.

To get them to retain their values, remove the declaration on them local to `Timer1Timer` and declare them as fields of TForm1 instead.

Btw, be aware that with this design, you are going to run into other issues, like how to handle concurrent access to the network textfile, etc, but they are not related to the specific point you asked about.

Comment: Only `filedate2` needs to be persistent, `filedate1` can and should remain a local variable. Also, don't forget to check `FileAge()` for failure before using `filedate1`. Consider using the other overloaded version of `FileAge()` (the one you are using is deprecated), which offers better error handling and more accurate output.

Answer (score 1):

The problem it that you are openning and closing file every time the timer ticks.
Open the file on `TForm1.FormCreate` by a `TFileStream` with `fmOpenReadWrite or fmOpenShareDenyNone` parameters, close it on `TForm1.FormDestroy`, and read it on `TForm1.Timer1Timer` if the number of read bytes are greater than zero convert the buffer to string and add it to the richedit.

Comment: Be careful with partial buffer reads, though. If the buffer does not contain complete character code sequences, the conversion may fail. Since the code is expecting lines, you should make sure a line break exists before converting the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because everytime you are resetting the filedate1 and filedate2 when the procedure runs. A better way to implement this function is to return the lastwrite time from the procedure and call the procedure on timer with the lastwrite time that was returned to you. Then you can compare the current time and the last time and do the refresh. On the first loop pass the current time and then keep using the lastread time in all subsequent calls and the result of which will keep updating the lastread time.